# iOS Safari doesn't ask to "Save Password" on login form

Tags: laravel

I made login form with Laravel 6.x.

**command:**

```
$ composer require laravel/ui
$ php artisan ui vue --auth
```

**template(default):**

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
    @csrf

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email" autofocus>

            @error('email')
                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                </span>
            @enderror
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="current-password">

            @error('password')
                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                </span>
            @enderror
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}>

                <label class="form-check-label" for="remember">
                    {{ __('Remember Me') }}
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row mb-0">
        <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                {{ __('Login') }}
            </button>

            @if (Route::has('password.request'))
                <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                    {{ __('Forgot Your Password?') }}
                </a>
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

When inputting items and sending, iOS Safari doesn't ask to "Save Password".

Here are the things I tried:

- Change `<button type="submit">` to `<input type="submit">`
- Add `autocomplete="on"` to form
- Add `<input name="user***">` to form ("*" is any string)

Is your login form no problem?
What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks correct. Tried it in Safari and it works well.

It looks like you did by accident click `Never for this website` earlier on the save password prompt.

Open Safari, click Safari -> Preferences -> Passwords -> search for the domain and check if you see a property with `never saved` in the password column.

Delete that property and refresh your page and it will ask you to save the credentials again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I checked it, but there was no problem.

For an unknown reason, I found approach to the problem. 1.Inputting items. / 2.Tap "Password" on iOS keyboard. / 3.iOS Setting->Password & Accounts -> Website & App Password / 4.Delete served password. / 5.Login again / 6.Since then iOS safari ask "Save Password".

Comment: Sorry I didn't read it was Safari on iOS, my response was for Safari on Mac. Your right for iOS, you can reset the password via Settings app -> Passwords and accounts -> Passwords -> Search for domain and click it -> Edit -> Delete.

Comment: That's right. The root cause is unknown, this thread is close. Thank you.